# google.docs is not a function

Tags: node.js, google-api

I want to use Google's Docs API but am running into an issue. I followed https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/nodejs but am having trouble setting it up.

My index.js looks like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {SimpleResponse, BasicCard, SignIn, Image} = require('actions-on-google');

const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
const people = google.people('v1');
const drive = google.drive('v3');
const docs = google.docs('v1');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // Enable lib debugging statements
```

My package.json:

```
  "name": "DialogflowFirebaseWebhook",
  "description": "Firebase Webhook dependencies for a Dialogflow agent.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "semistandard --fix \"**/*.js\"",
    "start": "firebase deploy --only functions, node index.js",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "googleapis": "^27.0.0",
    "actions-on-google": "2.2.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "0.6.1",
    "dialogflow": "0.6.0",
    "client-oauth2": "4.2.5"
  }
}
```

Showing only the relevant parts of my script, since it's pretty long, I get this error when I try to run the actual script.

> Detailed stack trace: TypeError: google.docs is not a function

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, the [doc reference](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/nodejs) you have shows this: `const docs = google.docs({version: 'v1', auth});`, not what you have.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have anywhere near the current version39 of google apis installed.  You have version 27.  Did you do: `npm install googleapis@39 --save` like the doc says?

Comment: Can't believe I missed that part. Updating to v39 worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turning my comment into an answer...

It doesn't look like you have anywhere near the current version39 of google apis installed. 
You have version 27.

Please run `npm install googleapis@39 --save` like the doc says.